# coerce_timestamps does not work in write_parquet in Apache arrow R package

Tags: r, apache-arrow

i am trying to truncate timestamps to milliseconds when writing a parquet file.

with:

```
tutu <- as.POSIXct("2020/06/03 18:00:00",tz = "UTC")
```

if i do:

```
write_parquet(data.frame(tutu),"~/Downloads/tutu.test.parquet")
```

i get 1591207200000000

if i do:

```
write_parquet(data.frame(tutu),"~/Downloads/tutu.test.parquet", coerce_timestamps = "ms", allow_truncated_timestamps = TRUE)
```

i get the error message:

```
Error in parquet___ArrowWriterProperties___Builder__coerce_timestamps(unit) : 
  argument "unit" is missing, with no default
```

what am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of arrow are you using? According to the code https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/4b8cbee11735d7a97a6150938fbee8fba95d8d9e/r/R/parquet.R#L194-L197 , the unit should always be ensured by the code beforehand.

Comment: I am using version 0.17.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug; see discussion on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9219